# Request conflict symfony action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I have an Ajax call that calls an action in the controller.

The Ajax call looks like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.editQuestionButton', function() {
    var question_id = $(this).data('question');
    console.log(question_id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/dashboard/form/AjaxEditQuestionForm/" + question_id + "",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#form-modal').html(data);
        }
    });

});

$(document).on('click', '.modal .fn-submit', function() {
    $(this).closest('.modal').find('form').submit();
});
```

And this is the action.

```
/**
     * @Route("/AjaxEditQuestionForm/{question}")
     * @Template
     * @ParamConverter("question", class="AppBundle:Question")
     */
    public function ajaxEditQuestionFormAction(Request $request, $question)
    {
        $edit_question_form = $this->createForm(new AddQuestionType(), $question);

        $edit_question_form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($edit_question_form->isValid()) {

            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_form_create');
        }
        else{
          die();
        }


        return array(
          'question' => $question,
          'editAjaxQuestionForm' => $edit_question_form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

The problem is that the action never returns the form but goes straight into checking if the form is valid. 
I figure this has something to do with the `$request` but I'm not sure how to change this.

The action should first get the data from the Ajax call, return the form and if the form is submitted, check if the form is valid and flush the Question entity.

Any idea on how I should do this?

Comment: isn't `die()` in else statement the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Well, I removed that and it returns the form now. So that is solved. But now it just completely ignores the if statement.

Comment: Change your `die()` to `return false;`

Comment: probably your form is just invalid, you may debug it using `$edit_question_form->getErrors()`. Btw, in your AJAX call you submit no data, maybe that's why the form is always invalid.

Comment: Now I get 'The controller must return a response (false given).'

Comment: @RomaKliuchko Strange thing is that when I remove the else, a new entity is created instead of the old one being updated.

Comment: Maybe `$em->persist($edit_question_form->getData())` before flushing will do the trick.

Comment: Still creates a new entity. I think I'm going to have to review my code again because something is not quite right.